# Why can't we use len() function intertwined with len() function in python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use python's `len` method, but the results are not as I would expect. For example:

```
>>> len('len("123456789123456789")')
25
```

It is working but the result is 25. I wanted that result should be 2.

Comment: could you describe what do you exactly want to calculate  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns 25 because `'len("123456789123456789")'` is a string of length 25. To get 2, your code should be `len(str(len("123456789123456789")))`

Answer (score 1):

`'len(....)'` does not turn the result of `len` into a string. For that, you need to call `str` explicitly:

```
len(str(len("123456789123456789")))
```

or use an f-string literal.

```
len(f'{len("123456789123456789")}')
```